# Odoo 10 - Move 1 unit to scrap location

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Greetings to everyone.

I'm expanding the hr.employee class to add employee equipment. As this equipment will sooner or later need to be replaced, I want to make a button so that if a checkbox is marked, it will transfer a unit from the stock location to scrap location.

The reason is to have an updated inventory and a history of the use of these elements. I have recently started programming using the framework provided by Odoo and the truth is that I am somewhat lost.

```
    class HrEmployeeLprl(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.employee'

# Botón actualizar
@api.one
@api.depends('hr', 'stock')
def action_lprl_update_inventory(self):
    if self.renew_glasses:
        move = self.env['stock.move'].create({
            'name': '',
            'location_id': self.glasses.property_stock_production.id,
            'location_dest_id': self.scrap_location.id,
            'product_id': self.glasses.id,
            'product_uom': self.glasses.uom_id.id,
            'product_uom_qty': 1
        })
        move._action_confirm()
        move._action_assign()
        move.move_line_ids.write({qty_done: 1})
        move._action_done()

glasses = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='product.product', 
    domain="[('categ_id', '=', 'LPRL / Gafas'), ('qty_available', '>', 0)]",
    string=u'Equipo de protección visual',
    help=u'Si no se muestra ningún producto compruebe que existan productos de la categoría en cuestión y que el stock sea mayor de 0'
)
renew_glasses = fields.Boolean(string="¿Renovar equipo de protección visual?")
scrap_location = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='stock.location',
    string=u'Destino del desecho',
    help=u'¿En donde se almacena el desecho?'
)
```

It throws the following message in the log:

```
> /srv/http/odoo/odoo10/custom-addons/hr_lprl/models/hr_employee_lprl.py(34)action_lprl_update_inventory()
-> move._action_confirm()
```

And the view remains freezed.
I would appreciate advice and references where to go deeper, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Juanma Beltran Osa

As error Suggest on Odoo-10 `stock.move` does not have the method called 
`_action_confirm` it is the `action_confirm`.

Try to check on Odoo-10 with the object that has those methods which you were trying to access and perform the operation.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Dipen Shah. It has helped me.

Comment: @JuanmaBeltranOsa You can feel free to accept the answer. It would be helpful for other community members in the future for reference.